# Iterm2: tmux support not working with windows WSL (tmux -cc)

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I use iterm2 on my local MacOS and tmux V3.0a on the target (Windows 10 WSL). When I init a connection with "tmux -CC" I can see something that looks like control traffic. I'd expect that this traffic should be be processed by iterm2 instead of being printed. Also I get no prompt:

```
ash@mother:/mnt/c/Users/ash$ tmux -CC
1000p%begin 1592235397 281 0
%end 1592235397 281 0
%window-add @2
%sessions-changed
%session-changed $2 2
%window-renamed @2 tmux
%output %2 To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".\015\012See "man sudo_root" for details.\015\012\015\012
%output %2 ash@mother:/mnt/c/Users/ash$
%window-renamed @2 bash
%exit
```

Setup:
MacOS Catalina -> SSH -> Windoze 10 -> WSL1 (bash) -> tmux V3.0a

Any ideas why iterm2 does type the control traffic instead of executing it ?

iterm2 Options tried:
OFF/ON: Automatic bury the tmux client session after connecting
ON: Use tmux profile
ON: Status bar shows tmux status bar content

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is trimming off the `\033P` at the start of the leading DCS sequence (`\033P1000p`) which iTerm2 uses to detect control mode has been entered. I think you will need to report this to the terminal developers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for giving a hint. I'll report and leave this thread open until I get response.